# Passing.getText() String to another class

Tags: java, swing, reflection, awt, jtextfield

I'm currently working on a first year university project and I have a problem, although I doubt it's a very complicated one, but I've been searching and I just can't find a suitable answer to it.

The problem concerns two classes. A gui class (class1) and another class (class2), when I run the code the second class gives me a nullpointerexception when trying to retrieve the getText() String in class2 from class1.

I have a JTextField in class1 and am trying to pass through the .getText() value to class2 and store it in a String type variable.

The current code I'm trying to achieve this with is the following (simplified):

```
 public class Class1 {

    private JTextField textField = new JTextField("Something");

      public Class1() {}
    ...
    public String getTextFieldString() {
      return textField.getText();
  }
}

 public class Class2 {

   public Class2(Class1 class1) {
    c1=class1
   }
    private c1 Class1 = new Class1();
    private String s = new String();
    ...
    s = c1.getTextFieldString();
}
```

I'm pretty new to coding, I've read that maybe I need to pass through an argument somewhere and I assume that's because textField is not static in itself, it changes when somebody enters a new value. (sorry for stating the obvious there.)

Anyway, help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may want to read up on some of the basics first including how Java implements object oriented principles and all about how Java reference variables work. This will help your GUI programming immensely.

Comment: And where exactly are you calling `new Class2(c1)`, like in my answer?

Comment: Ah, I only saw the top piece of your code, I was referring to that. You must have submitted it early, or I'm just being a moron which is highly likely.

Comment: Note that `private c1 Class1` is not a valid declaration; you may have meant `private Class1 c1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may help to review the [*prescribed*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) [*initialization order*](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#init) in Java. In particular, the `textField` instance variable initializer should be complete by the time a valid `Class1` instance exists. One way to violate this order is to construct `Class1` and `Class2` on different threads. To preclude this, Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), as shown in the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067399/230513 */
public class NewJavaGUI extends JPanel {

    public NewJavaGUI() {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2(class1);
        this.add(class1.textField);
        this.add(new JLabel(class2.s));
    }

    private static class Class1 extends Object {

        private final JTextField textField = new JTextField("Something");

        public Class1() {} // implicit

        public String getTextFieldString() {
            return textField.getText();
        }
    }

    private static class Class2 extends Object {

        private final Class1 c1;
        private final String s;

        public Class2(Class1 class1) {
            c1 = class1;
            s = c1.getTextFieldString();
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("NewJavaGUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewJavaGUI().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could pass a reference to `Class1` in the constructor of `Class2` and save it in an attribute, and every time `Class2` needs the text, simply call the `getText()` method on the attribute.

```
public class Class2 {
    private Class1 class1;
    public Class2(Class1 reference) {
        class1 = reference;
    }
    public void someMethod() {
        String s = class1.getTextFieldString();
    }
}
```

Now, when you instantiate a `Class2` object:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2(c1);
```

Comment: Ah, I'm really sorry, I have a reference to class1 in class 2 already and I think I'm already doing what you're suggesting and it's still not working. I should have been more clear, I'll edit my code and put that bit in.

Comment: If you're getting a `NullPointerException` it means that you forgot to instantiate some object (`... = new ...`), somewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're interested in knowing when someone modifies the text in the text field.  My first piece of advice is to look at the java tutorials whenever you have a specific question about a Swing component.  Specifically, look at the addActionListener method in the [JTextField tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), including the [Text Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java) example.